# Expo React Native app crash on physical device after eas build

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

my expo app crash when launch on physical device after eas build

build log

[stderr]
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.

[stderr]
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

[stderr]
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.

[stderr]
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "social",
    "slug": "social",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/logo.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/logo.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/logo.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "package": "com.gauravgajjar.social"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/logo.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "3eaec0b8-7c13-43eb-bb50-ff0ab227497a"
      }
    },
    "runtimeVersion": {
      "policy": "appVersion"
    },
    "updates": {
      "url": "https://u.expo.dev/3eaec0b8-7c13-43eb-bb50-ff0ab227497a"
    }
  }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "social",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.13",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.17",
    "expo": "^49.0.11",
    "expo-av": "~13.4.1",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.3.2",
    "expo-secure-store": "~12.3.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5",
    "expo-system-ui": "~2.4.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.18.13",
    "formik": "^2.4.3",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "^0.72.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-virtualized-view": "^1.0.0",
    "yup": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

eas.json

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 5.2.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "preview": {
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      },
      "channel": "main"
    },
    "preview2": {
      "android": {
        "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleRelease"
      },
      "channel": "main"
    },
    "preview3": {
      "developmentClient": true
    },
    "production": {}
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

i re-install all dependencies, clear cache of npm, expo, check code, analyze code but dont work

Comment: it successfully work on expo go but dont work in physical device

Comment: Did you use an android or an iOS device?
Did you try ```eas build --platform android --local```

Comment: I am using Android device

Comment: eas build --platform android --local not working

Comment: How does it fail ?

Comment: This command is only supported in Linux and Mac OS I am using windows 10